# What is this insect, the bite of which is causing deaths?

Tags: entomology, nomenclature

This insect is currently found in Kolkata, and in many parts of West Bengal, India. Its bite results in a fever, and if not treated immediately, the victim dies. This is the insect:

[image: Red Clover Mite]

It seems that the insect belongs to the family of spiders due to its eight feet. But I can't conclude any more. Does someone know what this insect is, and how to be safe from it?

Comment: Howdy, is this really your picture?  I found it on [this website](http://townandcountrysolutions.com/identify-a-pest/clover-mites/).  Just mite want to attribute it.  :)

Comment: From what I can tell, the website you got this image from provides the ID of this insect, so it's unclear what you're asking..

Comment: @rotaredom it came out on the newspapers, and it's bite is actually brutal.

Comment: This is a plant-feeding insect. It is of no danger to humans. Your article sounds a bit sensationalized. There are some small creatures that can kill you, but they are few and far between.

Comment: I am sorry that my question is partially incorrect. It is true that this insect is spreading the disease, but it is not the only one. The disease is [this](http://timesofindia.indiatimes.com/city/kolkata/Scrub-Typhus-the-insect-borne-disease/articleshow/53728840.cms).

Comment: Well, you have your answer at least! Please note the disease **may** result in death if left untreated. No one dies immediately.

Answer (score 1):

You were right to suspect arachnid. Its a red clover mite. But they normally don't bite humans or cause diseases. Could you post some links to news articles talking about the disease?

Comment: I could have gladly given the site, but it's in bengali and I couldn't find an English one.

Comment: Its ok, can I have the bengali site?

Comment: I am sorry that my question is partially incorrect. It is true that this insect is spreading the disease, but it is not the only one. The disease is [this](http://timesofindia.indiatimes.com/city/kolkata/Scrub-Typhus-the-insect-borne-disease/articleshow/53728840.cms).

Comment: ah that makes more sense now. Thanks for the link